# Improving the Fighter through research

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I would like to enable fighters to research new moves in a way similar to wizard researching new spells. Currently, the mechanism of fighter improvement goes through abilities, but I feel like it's limited. You have very specific abilities allowing you "special moves" dealing more damage, but that's basically it.

Ideally the fighter characters should be able to research new, original abilities with the desired effect. Combination of actions with another fighter (such as double assaults) should also be possible.

Does anything like this already exist, or do I have to develop it from scratch? If this were the case, what would you do to keep the game balanced?

Comment: Do you mean Fighters, rather than Warriors?

Comment: just a warning, I have done something similar in an earlier campaign, and it tended to bog down the game. The fighters spent a LOT of time in game preparing to research these skills, and trying to work them in. I got the feeling that they were so excited to have these new abilities they took it too far. IMO, that was a positive and a negative.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I like [Tome of Battle: The Book of Nine Swords](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ex/20060802a).  It may or may not move the game into more of a martial arts atmosphere if you so desire.

Basically, those learning martial styles will learn "stances" (which confer certain benefits while maintained) and "maneuvers" (which reflect focused abilities and precision typified by special training and ki/chi/whatever).  There are three basic approaches into this form of martial prowess.  One is strongly weapon oriented.  A second is faith oriented.  And the third is finesse oriented.

At first, I was skeptical of the supplement.  After I finished it, I was sold.

(Please pardon me if the terminology isn't quite on the nose.  It has been a while since I've read the text.)

Comment: Yeah, Bo9S was going to be my answer too!

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, probably the best answer to your problem is tome of battle. I do not know if it has synergy skills, but it gives a nice flavor to all martial characters (something like a martial paladin , a war machine called warblade and a martial "wizard" called swordsage. There are maneuvers for these classes, essentially what you made for your campaign, but resembling spells as for their mechanics. They make playing a front line fighter interesting, without a necessity of PrCs. There is also some homebrew material that you could check online.

Comment: There are maneuvers, stances and another type of such skills, can't remember the name.